# Reading pixels from render buffer webgl2

Tags: webgl, webgl2

How can I read pixels from render buffer in webgl2? I've tried code below but I only get zeroes (0, 0, 0...) where I would except red and alpha to be not zero

```js
    const targetTexture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    const frameBuf = gl.createFramebuffer()!;
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuf);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture, 0);

    const depthBuf = gl.createRenderbuffer();
    gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, depthBuf);
    gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 512, 512);
    gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, depthBuf);

    const colorBuf = gl.createRenderbuffer();
    gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, colorBuf);
    gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.RGBA4, 512, 512);
    gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.RENDERBUFFER, colorBuf);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, 512, 512);
    gl.clearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.clearDepth(1.0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    const results = new Uint8Array (512 * 512 * 4);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, 512, 512, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, results);
    console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

So it appears code I posted actually works. The issue is that I am also using `gl.SCISSOR_TEST` (which is not included in the code above) and disabling it seems to resolve my problems.